# Implementing Django Model for existing MongoDB schema

Tags: mongodb, django-models, mongoengine

How can I convert something like this for Django Model that use mongoDB?

The following is a code snippet using node js and Mongo:

```
var HostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hostId: Number,
    name: String,
    host: String,
    items: {
        loaded: {type: Boolean, default: false},
        load: Array,
        cpu: Array,
    }
}, {versionKey: false});

var HostModel = mongoose.model('Host', HostSchema);
```